# Flutter: How can I dismiss a flushbar elsewhere in the code?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I would like to show a flushbar while something is being stored on my server. I can start it with an infinite duration, but can the flushbar be found elsewhere in the code and dismissed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you can, despite not knowing the package and by checking [the source code](https://github.com/AndreHaueisen/flushbar/blob/master/lib/flushbar.dart) you can assign it a `GlobalKey` and then call its methods through it.

```
final GlobalKey flushBarKey = GlobalKey();

Widget build(BuildContext) {
   return FlushBar(key: flushBarKey),
}

void foo(){
  (flushBarKey.currentWidget as FlushBar).dismiss();
}
```